# How to prove that $ a \bmod ( b \bmod a ) + b \bmod a \le \frac { a + b } 2 $?

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

The idea is to prove that after two iterations of the Euclid GCD algorithm, the sum of the two arguments would be less than half the original sum. Starting at $ a $ and $ b $, where $ a < b $, after the first iteration, the arguments are $ ( b \bmod a , a ) $ and after the second iteration, the arguments are $ \big( a \bmod ( b \bmod a ) , b \bmod a \big) $.

Using properties that $ b \bmod a \le a $ and $ b \bmod a \le b - a $ (if $ b \ge a $), I've reached the conclusion that the $ \operatorname {sum} \big( a \bmod ( b \bmod a ) , b \bmod a \big) \le 2 a $ but I'm completely at loss on how to reduce it further ($ \operatorname {sum} { } \le a $ would be enough to finish the proof). Is there any $ \bmod $ property that I'm missing to simplify this further?

Comment: @Mohsen Shahriari: use `\bmod` for the binary mod operator, *not* `\mod`.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for noting. I just knew `\mod` and `\pmod`, and used the obvious choice between them. Now, I know what to choose in the future.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari: After over 30 years of using $\TeX$ and $\LaTeX$, I still don't know what possessed Knuth to make the default the weirdly spaced one, and then defined separately the "binary mod" `\bmod` and the "parenthetical mod" `\pmod`....

Answer (score 0):

Let $ b = ka + r$, where $ 0 \leq r < a$ and $k\geq 1$. WTS

$$2\times(a \bmod r) + r \leq ka+a$$

**Hint:** Show that $ 2 \times( a \bmod r ) \leq a$.

> Split into cases
>  - $ r \leq a/2$
>  - $r > a/2$.

**Corollary:** $2\times(a \bmod r) + r < a+a \leq ka+a$.